# Best way to insert text file using ColdFusion & SQL?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfloop

I have some text files that I have to insert in one of my tables in SQL. I have separate table where my text file names are stored. I have to grab the name from that table and then use the `fileOpen()` to get the file from specific folder. After I finish that step I have the problem to decide what is the best way to do the next steps. So I have to use `fileReadLine()` to get the context of each text file row. Also I should not read the first line since that contains only column names. Second I have to check once I hit the end of the file. On the very end I have to loop and do the INSERT into the table. I was wondering is out there any new ways of doing this? My current code has two `cfloops` and that looks very inefficient. Here is my current code:

```
<!--- Grab stuff from File Table.  --->
<cfquery datasource="test" name="myQuery1">
    SELECT * 
    FROM FilesTxt
</cfquery> 

<cfloop query="myQuery1"> 
    <!--- Read File --->
    <cfset dataFile = fileOpen(here is my path&"\"&#FileName#, "read" ) /> 
    <cfset line = fileReadLine( dataFile ) />

    <!--- Loop to see if hit the end of file, if not, read next line --->
    <cfloop condition="!fileIsEOF( dataFile )">
        <cfset line = fileReadLine( dataFile ) />

        <cfif trim(line) NEQ "">
           <cfset line = #Replace(line,"'","","ALL")#>
           <cfset line = #Replace(line,'"',"","ALL")#>
           <!--- Build array of junk in the file --->
           <cfset sList = ListToArray(line, chr(9),'yes')>

           <cftry>
                <cfquery datasource="test" name="Insert">
                //Here is my Insert statement
                </cfquery>
           </cftry>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

I was thinking of doing separate loop that will create array with all elements that should be inserted and then to run another loop to do the insert. I'm not sure what is the best approach in this case. If anyone knows any other way please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Most databases have tools to for loading text files, which are usually far more efficient than looping.  The tools are DBMS specific. Do a search on MySQL - LOAD DATA, SQL Server - BULK INSERT, etcetera.  There are tons of examples.  (BTW, with database questions, always include your DBMS and version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop file lines directly like so:

```
<cfloop file="**path/filename**" index="LineOfMyFile">
    <cfoutput>#LineOfMyFile#</cfoutput> 
</cfloop>
```

The loop terminates at end of file so you don't really need the fileisEOF() function.

Inside your loop you can use list functions rather than looping through an array. If you know the positions of the items in your list. like so:

```
<cfloop file="**path/filename**" index="LineOfMyFile">

    <cfquery name="myinsert" datasource="#blah#">
        INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3)
        VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#listgetat(lineOfMyFile,1,char(9))#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value="#listgetat(lineofmyFile,2,char(9))#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value="#listgetat(lineofMyFile,3,char(9))#">)
    </cfquery>

</cfloop>
```

This would be a single loop. Depending on the size of your file it may or may not be more efficient. Also, there are usually checks for type, null, empty strings - stuff like that. So you might have some of that data massaging code before your insert. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice catch with `<cfloop file>` I didn't think of this. (A `ListLen()` check would be nice, as this will blow up for rows that for some reason have too few columns)

Comment: @MarkAKruger I have few more questions related to your answer above.Should I remove my Replace() code? Is that some how already done with in your code? Also with using listgetAt() I basically just specify the position of the element that I need from my file? Or I did not understand how that works... Also should I move my INSERT INTO ... part out of the cfloop and put the loop after the VALUES? I think that might be better option but not sure 100%?

Comment: I was testing listGetAt() that will specify the position but I still have my first line with the column names. How I can get rid of the first line from my .txt file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also cfloop file ignores the white space/empty strings in my file. That cause my columns to shift and change position. Is there any way how this can be fixed?

Comment: Set a counter to 1 outside the loop and increment (`counter ++`) at the end _inside_ the loop. Then bracket your insert code with `<cfif counter IS NOT 1>`.  As for the delimiters that's going to depend on the data.

Comment: As for empty strings (where 2 commas stack together as in ,,) yeah - that's an issue. you can insert a space there before your read the line (replace(string,",,",", ,")) or a pipe or something you can check for. listToArray() might give you the proper number of elements as an array - and then your insert would just be #myarray(2)# - where 2 is the same as your listgetat number.

Comment: Use Bulk insert.  Why make more than 1 call to Database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert 100,000 values into a table, there is no way around making 100,000 INSERT statements.

Specialized, database-proprietary tools or commands can do it in a more optimized fashion, but personally I don't see much wrong with a nested loop here.

```html
<cfquery name="files" datasource="test">
    SELECT FileName FROM FilesTxt
</cfquery> 

<cfloop query="files">
    <cfset file = fileOpen("here is my path\#FileName#", "read")>
    <cfset fileReadLine(file)>

    <cfloop condition="not fileIsEOF(file)">
        <cfloop list="#fileReadLine(file)#" delimiters="#Chr(9)#" index="item">
           <cftry>
                <cfquery datasource="test">
                    INSERT testTable (testColumn) VALUES (
                        <cfqueryparam value="#Trim(item)#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
                    )
                </cfquery>
           </cftry>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Notes:

- Don't do `SELECT *`. Name the columns you need.
- Don't comment the obvious. *"Grab stuff from File Table"* is an entirely superfluous comment, the code says that.
- Use proper variable names. `files` is much better than `myQuery1`.
- There is no need to use `##` *unless* you want to interpolate variable content into a string, into a CF tag attribute or into the output.

  ```html
  <cfset line = #Replace(...)#>   <!--- useless use of ## --->
  <cfset line = Replace(...)>     <!--- much better --->
  ```
- You can use `<cfloop list="">` to loop over a line from a CSV file. It's a simple list, after all.
- Always use `<cfqueryparam>` in your queries. This way you don't need to worry about quotes in the values. It also is more efficient that way in a loop.
- INSERT queries don't really need a `name`
- Avoid `<cftry>` without `<cfcatch>` unless you *really* don't care for errors.
- Last, but not least: CSV is a more complex format than one would think. "Just split it line-wise at the TAB character" will not work when TAB or NEWLINE is part of the value for some reason (which would be valid if the value is quoted). Look around for a CSV parser (maybe start [here](http://cflove.org/2012/12/working-with-csv-files-in-coldfusion.cfm)).

Comment: Use Bulk insert.  Why make more than 1 call to Database?

Comment: @LrakWortep Sure, but that's database-specific. There is no ColdFusion "bulk insert" command.

Comment: batch insert is t-sql and works for all versions of sql.  There isnt a regular "Insert" command in coldfusion either.  You write your sql and have it execute.

Comment: @LrakWortep Your approach is prone to SQL injection at worst, random syntax errors in the less worse case, and for larger inputs might hit the length limit of a single SQL statement. It might be an OK solution for a one-off, although for a one-off, a loop with a parameterized query is not that bad either. But it's not a particularly good solution for production use. I'd prefer a parameterized query anytime, or - for best performance - the proprietary CSV bulk load facility of the RDBMS in question.

Comment: Just saying this statement is absolutely false "there is no way around making 100,000 INSERT statements."

Answer (score -2):

All these answers are wrong.  If you want to insert a bunch of values use SQL BULK INSERT

```
<cfset myInserts = "">
<cfloop file="test" index = "line">
   <cfset myInserts = listAppend(myInserts,"(#line#)">
</cfloop>
<cfquery>
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES #preserveSingelQuotes(myInserts)#
</cfquery>
```